# A navigation menu that stays on top

Tags: jquery, css, uinavigationbar

I have gone through all the links about the same question like [sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019661/how-do-i-make-the-navigation-bar-of-my-site-stay-at-the-top-when-the-viewer-scro) and others.

But all the codes include this link http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js.

This link is altering my css alignments and only half of my navigation bar can be seen.

Anybody know why that ajax jQuery file is creating problem and solution to fix this issue.

[How do I make the navigation bar of my site stay at the top when the viewer scrolls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019661/how-do-i-make-the-navigation-bar-of-my-site-stay-at-the-top-when-the-viewer-scro)

Comment: But that's just a jQuery library. A pretty old one. Nothing to do with your CSS.

Comment: Yes. but it is creating some problem to my css and alignments are going wrong once i include it.

Comment: can you show your css for fixed navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions, I solved it by myself in a very simple way without using any jquery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $div = $('#sticky_navigation');
        if ($div.offset().top < $(this).scrollTop())  {
            $div.addClass('fixed');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() == '0')  {
            $div.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
</script>
```